# How to correctly join table which may return more than one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, join

I have a table Items which have the following columns:

> ItemId || AdminUserID || ItemName

And I try to join it with ItemAttributes:

> ItemAttributeId || ItemId || AttributeValue

where one ItemId can have several ItemAttributeId values assigned to it.

I created procedure to retrieve item values from two tables:

```
 SELECT 
    i.ItemID,
    i.AdminUserID,
    i.ItemName,
    attr1.AttributeValue as IsForEmailRobotProcessingValue,
    attr2.AttributeValue as RobotScheduledHoursValue -- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
FROM [dbo].[Items] i WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].ItemAttributes attr1 WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON attr1.ItemID = i.ItemID and attr1.ItemAttributeID = 1
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].ItemAttributes attr2 WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON attr2.ItemID = i.ItemID and attr2.ItemAttributeID = 2
WHERE ((attr1.AttributeValue IS NOT NULL AND attr1.AttributeValue = 'true') OR 
    @OnlyForEmailRobotProcessing = 0)
ORDER BY ItemName
```

What I don't like here is that I LEFT JOIN two times the same table and created different aliases for each join according to the same ItemId. Is there any better way to LEFT JOIN only one time and created two different aliases for each ItemAttributeId? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    i.ItemID,
    i.AdminUserID,
    i.ItemName,
    attr1.AttributeValue1 as IsForEmailRobotProcessingValue,
    attr1.AttributeValue2 as RobotScheduledHoursValue 
FROM [dbo].[Items] i WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN
            (select ItemId,  (select AttributeValue 
                              from  [dbo].ItemAttributes a
                              where a.ItemId = b.ItemId and a.ItemAttributeID = 1) as AttributeValue1,
                              (select AttributeValue 
                              from  [dbo].ItemAttributes c
                              where c.ItemId = b.ItemId and c.ItemAttributeID = 2) as AttributeValue2
             from    [dbo].ItemAttributes b  WITH(NOLOCK)
             where b.ItemId = i.ItemID  and b.ItemAttributeID in (1,2)

                ) attr1 on i.ItemId  = attr1.ItemId

WHERE ((attr1.AttributeValue IS NOT NULL AND attr1.AttributeValue = 'true') OR 
    @OnlyForEmailRobotProcessing = 0)
ORDER BY ItemName
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think this is more efficient than my version?

Comment: You have to check you execution plans in order to measure performance.